# Regex capture group flows into second match set

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to match multiple inputs in the same regex to capture the number following.
If the input doesnt match the first group then I have issues because all previous capture groups are still captured despite it doesnt match they group. I believe I need to use a `lookaround` assertion, but I am not familiar with those.

Sample input:

```
wordA 123456
wordA: 123456
wordA : 123456
wordA R123465
wordA: R123456
wordA : R123456
wordB R123465
```

WordA has both optional `:` and `R`. So far I have this: `/(?:wordA :?R?(\d+)|wordB R(\d+))/i`.
Using the last sample input provides this result:

```
array
  0 => string 'wordB R123456' (length=13)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string '123456' (length=6)
```

Wanted result is:

```
array
  0 => string 'wordB R123465' (length=13)
  1 => string '123456' (length=6)
```

Any ideas how to fix ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your alternation

```
/(?:wordA :?R?(\d+)|wordB R(\d+))/i
              ^^^^^        ^^^^^
             Group 1       Group 2
```

So if your regex matches the second alternative, the result will be in group 2 (`array[2]`) and the first group will be empty.

Change it to this

```
(?:wordA :?R?|wordB R)(\d+)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30lgs)

Then your number will always be in the first group (because there is only one)

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was because of having 2 groups, but I figured if the first part didnt match, then the rest would be ignored. This was a false assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining two capturing groups, therefore you'll get two as a result. The regex implementation does not care if only one of them can match at a time. You could rewrite your expression to

```
/(?:wordA :?R?|wordB R)(\d+)/i
```

to avoid defining two capturing groups. Note that `:?R?` is not sufficient to match your test cases with `_:_` or `:_`. 
To get those, you could use

```
/(?:wordA ?:? R?|wordB R)(\d+)/i
```